# Pass file as argument to Docker run

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile

is is possible to pass file as an argument to docker . I have an dockerized java application which expects the properties file to be passed as an argument and then it reads file and performs start up and other activities .Is it possible to implement this.

Comment: Docker run , app inside container expects file to be passer on run time

Comment: Generally what you want to do declare an environment variable in your dockerfile and override that when you `docker run` https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#env-environment-variables

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You have to set [entrypoint](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) and [cmd](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) properly.

When additional arguments are passed on the command line, these will be used as *command* instead and be passed to the entry point.